# Reading binary data from accelerometer device into R

Tags: r, matlab, binary

Essentially I want to know if there is a practical way to read a particular kind of binary file in to R. I have some Matlab code which does what I want but ideally I want to be able to do this in R.
The Matlab code is:

```
fid = fopen('filename');
A(:) = fread(fid, size*2, '2*uint8=>uint8',510,'ieee-le');
```

and so far in R I've been using:

```
to.read = file("filename", "rb")
bin = readBin(to.read, integer(), n = 76288, endian = "little")
```

The confusion I'm having is with the 3rd and 5th argument in the matlab function `fread()`- I don't understand exactly what `'2*uint8=>uint8'` or `'ieee-le'` mean in terms of interpreting the binary data. This is what is holding me back from implementing it in R.

Also, the file extension is .cwa, apparently this is a very efficient format to have high frequency (100Hz) activity data recorded in.

Comment: You are vague. Please explain what your issue is.

Comment: I'm not a matlab person, but [the `fread` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) seems clear enough on the 3rd/5th arguments: the 3rd is `precision`, mapping the input to the output formats; and the 5th is `machinefmt`, stating that the binary data is in [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) order (least-significant byte first in a multi-byte numeric representation). To troubleshoot, you might want to use R's `raw()` instead of `integer()` and verify everything is being interpreted correctly.

Comment: Hi @MichaelDunne-Willows, what kind of file is it? What file extension does the file you are trying to read in is. csv, txt. dbd. If you tell us that I might help

Comment: Hi @DerekCorcoran, it's extension is .CWA. Apparently this is a very efficient format to have high frequency (100Hz) activity data recorded in.

Comment: @MichaelDunne-Willows Can you upload a CWA file or send me one to derek.corcoran.barrios@gmail.com? I want to try some solutions but I can't find any example data, or guide me to a link to find one